# Macbook Air usb to ethernet problem

Tags: mac, macbook-pro, usb, ethernet

When I first bought, it totally worked. but now, it works after many plug and re-unplugs. What should I do? and it keeps not detecting the usb to ethernet cable.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you should try is remove the interface in your System Preferences, Network.
Select the USB adaptor, click the - sign, then re-add the interface.

That could fix your problem.

Comment: It could be the plug/adapter (mechanical!

Comment: Ha! I started to ask a duplicate of this question, and was directed here. Your answer did it. I almost returned this USB to EN adaptor. Works fine now. +1